# Multiply two float elements in an array that is referenced using pointers

Tags: c, pointers

How do I multiply two values that are inside an array that is referenced using a pointer? Example:

```
void func(float *a[3]) {
    //a[0]*a[1] // generates compiler errors
    float x = (*a[0])*(*a[1]) // this does not generate any errors when compiled but results in Segmentation fault 11. However it works when printing out to console: printf("%f", (*a[0])); => 1
}

int main() {
    float arr[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    float *ptr = arr;

    func(&ptr);
    
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify whether you want to use an array of floats or an array of pointers to floats. I assume you want to use an array of floats, because the shown code is very far away from having a correctly initialised array of pointers to floats.

Comment: In order not to confuse or distract potential answerers, I recommend to do something with the multiplication result in your [mre], in order to test/demonstrate success. Maybe `printf("%f\n", x);`.

Comment: You are over-thinking it. Drop all of the indirection operators and call `func(arr);` and in the function `float x = a[0] * a[1];` The function should be eith `void func(float a[])` or `void func(float *a)`

Comment: @Yunnosch This is a minimally reproducible example.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks, changing it to a pointer and not an "array pointer" fixed it! You're the best!

Comment: It is an MRE yes, and no. Yes, it is compilable and matches what you describe. No, it does not usefully demonstrate the success/failure; i.e. it is improveable on the "reproducable" if reproducing is (rather nitpickishly, I admit) understood as making something visible/obsevable. Otherwise you would have very likely noticed that you can calculate as shown, but not what you want to calculate. It might even make the problem visible by forcing the compiler to actually calculate, which I think it currently optimises away. Also, I did not want to use "MRE" without explainin the acronym.

Comment: By making visible (on top of the printfed value being most likely wrong) I mean that when the compiler actually accesses, you have a good (though not guaranteed) chance at getting a segfault. As I said, the code is far from correctly initialising... Also, the shown code does not give any indication on why you ask. If it seems to work, why should you ask? Demonstrating a wrong result or a segfault would clarify that. And finally, I actually did describe your code as MRE, "in your minimal reproducible example".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You program should be more like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(float *a) {
  float x = a[0] * a[1];
  printf("%f", x);
}

int main() {
  float arr[3] = {2, 4, 6};
  float *ptr = arr;

  func(ptr);
    
  return 1;
}
```

`arr` and `ptr` have the same value really, which is an address of the beginning of float numbers in RAM (you can think of it as RAM but in reality it is virtual memory).  You pass that pointer into `func`, and then `a` is a pointer to the very first float number. You can use those values either by `a[1]` or `*(a + 1)`.  So you can write `a[0] * a[1]` or `*a * *(a + 1)`. You can also directly use `func(arr)` instead of `func(ptr)` because `arr` and `ptr` have the same value.

Comment: Thanks, I needed to change the variable in the func function!

Comment: I'd rather write `func(float a[])` instead of `func(float *a)`. It is exactly the same thing, but it expresses that `a`  is an array.

Answer (score 1):

`float *a[3]` is an array of three pointers to `float`, not a pointer to an array length 3 of `float`. Since this is a function parameter, the declaration of the parameter of array of `float *` is adjusted to be a pointer to a `float *`. Therefore, the parameter declaration `float *a[3]` is equivalent to `float **a`.

Your code passes `&ptr` to the function. `ptr` is of type `float *`, so `&ptr` is of type `float **`. So `&ptr` is compatible with the function parameter. However, `ptr` is not an array of `float *`. It is a single `float *`. The rules of C allow `&ptr` to treated as a pointer to the first element of an array of length 1 of `float *`. Inside the function `func`, `a[0]` is valid, but `a[1]` is out of bounds.

To pass an array to a function, the usual technique is to pass a pointer to the first element of the array. The simplest solution to your problem is to change the function parameter to `float *a` (or `float a[]`), as in the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(float *a) {
    float x = a[0] * a[1];
    printf("%f", x);
}

int main() {
    float arr[3] = {1, 2, 3};

    func(arr);
    return 0;
}
```